# Page intro - body fade in

Tags: jquery, css, html, wordpress

I have a wordpress site, and I am using [supersized](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-supersized/) plugin for full-screen a background image slider.

I want to display static fullscreen background image before the body is loaded with all the site content.

For now, I've added this HTML:

```
<html class="no-js">
```

(I added the class no-js to the html tag)

To the css, I added this line:

```
.js body { display: none; }
```

And on the footer, I added this jQuery code:

```
<script>
  jQuery('body').fadeIn(5000); // fadein time in ms
</script>
```

From here, I don't know how to continue.

I tried to display background using jquery, but... if I hide the body - I can't actually do anything until it will load by the jQuery, right? What are the alternative options?

Comment: What's the result with your current code?

Comment: The whole body is hide, and after 5000 ms its fade-in. i want - before the body is full fade in, to display full screen background image.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand clearly what you want. Showing image before body is fully loaded? why not having separate div for this background(absolute 100%) and separate one for other stuff? All inside body ofcourse? You can show the background for 5s, then hide it and show other stuff

Comment: For that reason i need a yellow duck on my desk. sometimes the brain is 101% use.

Comment: @trainoasis So, by your suggestion... if i have on the page divs like: #nav, #footer, #header ... i need to hide them all, and to display #first-bg, and only after 5s to hide it and show the rest?

Comment: Can you fake it, and just have a random image as the background that's not necessarily loaded by the slider?

Comment: @Oshrib, hide all of them except your bg in css, then you only need to show them after 5s. You can easily show everything and hide one certain element in jQuery using not()

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML from this:

```
<body>
    *your content*
<body>
```

To this:

```
<body>
    <div id="bgimage"></div>
    <div id="content">*your content*</div>
<body>
```

Add this css to `#bgimage`:

```
#bgimage { position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-image: url(*image url*); background-size: cover; }
```

And instead of fading in the body, fade in `#content` as you fade out `#bgimage`

I think this is what @trainoasis meant by their comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
    $(function() {
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        $('body').removeClass('preload'); //remove class preload to hide the image
      }, 5000);
    });
```

```css
    body,
    html {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
    }
    body.preload:after {
      content: " ";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      background: url(/* Your image */) no-repeat center center/100% 100% #000;
      z-index: 999;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="preload">
  <h3>content of body...</h3>
</body>
```

Adding and removing the class preload does the trick, as the css pseudo element is based on this class.

Hope this helps

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/groumisg/x4zpe8Lm/2/) to showcase the above code